# how to stream live audio video using Java EE?

Tags: java, video, audio, jakarta-ee, stream

I wanted to stream live audio & video from one client to another over the internet, I'm using WebSphere community edition as my server, and I'm supposed to do this task using Java EE technologies.

I'm doing this as a part of the project for IBM TGMC.

Which particular API or tech is best suited for my purpose?

I googled for JMF, but heard that it's a bit complex and old. Is there a better alternative?

Answer (score 0):

JMF is complex because media handling is complex - there is no 'magic wand'.  It is not only old but abandoned.

JMF works just fine for the codecs it supports, but those codecs are not as compressive as some that were developed later.  OTOH if you can develop an encoder/decoder for the codec of interest, it should be relatively simple to get JMF to use it - JMF supports new codecs via the SPI.

No there is no better alternative that I know about.  FMJ was designed as an alternative to JMF, but last I heard, it had also been abandoned.